# Entity Data Filtering - payara41-web-4.1.1.164 with Jersey - How to ObjectProvider

Tags: java, rest, jersey, payara, object-graph

I am trying to obtain the ObjectProvider in a MessageBodyReader. But it ends up with the and CDI-Error: "WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ObjectProvider with qualifiers @Default". The idea is to map the ObjectProvider from Jersey to a EntityGraph from JPA. Below the code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.FilteringHelper;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.ObjectGraph;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.ObjectProvider;

@ApplicationScoped
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ObjectGraphMessageBodyReader extends JacksonJsonProvider {

  @Inject
  private javax.inject.Provider<ObjectProvider<ObjectGraph>> provider;
```

I gabbed the code from: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/entity/filtering/FilteringMessageBodyProvider.java

Comment: Have you registered `EntityFilteringFeature` or `SecurityEntityFilteringFeature`?

Comment: No, but this seems to work: 
 @Context
 protected ObjectProvider provider;